# Group records that has a start and end date by Distinct Price MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How would I write a query to group records that have the same price and group the start date and, the end date. The database records are as follows:

```
    Product Name        Product Date Price
    Blue Man Group Tier 2 2014-12-31 54.00
    Blue Man Group Tier 2 2014-12-30 54.00
    Blue Man Group Tier 2 2014-12-29 54.00
    Blue Man Group Tier 2 2014-12-27 63.00
    Blue Man Group Tier 2 2014-12-25 54.00
    Blue Man Group Tier 2 2014-12-24 54.00
    Blue Man Group Tier 2 2014-12-23 54.00
    Blue Man Group Tier 2 2014-12-22 54.00
```

This is the initial output I would like to accomplish based on the above database records.

```
Blue Man Group Tier 2 2014-12-31 - 2014-12-29 54.00
Blue Man Group Tier 2 2014-12-27 - 2014-12-27 63.00
Blue Man Group Tier 2 2014-12-25 - 2014-12-22 54.00
```

I have used PHP in order to see If I can make this happen with an array. 
This is what I have so far:

```
    $q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE attid='11'");

$k=0;
$result= array();
$filter_result = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q1)){
    $array_count= count($result)-1;
    $price = trim($r['price']);

    if($k == 0){
        $result[$k] = $price;
        $k++;
        continue;
    }
    if($price != $result[$array_count]){
        $result[$k] = $price;
        $filter_result[] = $r['productName']. ' ' .$r['productDate']. ' ' .$r['price'];
        $k++;
    } 


}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($filter_result);
```

This is the Results From the array.

```
    [1] => Blue Man Group Tier 2 2014-12-31 54.00
    [2] => Blue Man Group Tier 2 2014-12-27 63.00
    [3] => Blue Man Group Tier 2 2014-12-25 54.00
```

The price shows but I cannot get the dates to group from the start date to the end date of the price.

Comment: have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: This is the kind of thing easily handled by the application.